# Check if android menu button is pressed on website

Tags: android, jquery, web

just out of curiosity:
Is it possible for a web page to check if the android menu button is pressed? I want to be able to perform a jquery action if the button is pressed. the page itself will open in a browser that does not provide a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't**. The browser handles the menu before the web page, unless the the browser app is from you, (which you can configure to trigger certain events to the web page). The possible solution you can achieve is to create a menu on the web page itself.